# django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'test_xxx.django_content_type' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-1.4, django-unittest

I get the following error when I run the django unittest.

```
python manage.py test

...
...
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (1146, "Table 'test_xxx.django_content_type' doesn't exist")
```

Please guide me on what I might be doing wrong.

Is this has to do with the order of INSTALLED_APPS ?

Comment: Do you have django.contrib.contenttypes in your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @fasouto - yes I do have django.contrib.contenttypes in INSTALLED_APPS